# While running "docker-compose up" getting Error "ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While running "docker-compose up" getting error

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
>     in "./docker-compose.yml", line 8, column 14

My docker compose file as below;

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4.21
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: myusername
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPass
    ports:
      -'5432:5432'
    volumes:
          ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

      redis:
        image: redis: 5.0.5
        ports:
          - '6379:6379'
          volumes:
             ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data

            mobydock:
              build: .
              command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --access-logfile - "mobydock.app:create_app()"
              environment:
                PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
                links:
                  - postgres
                  - redis
                volumes:
                  - .:/mobydock
                  ports:
                    - '8000:8000'
```

I have tried by changing some signs before the volumes path.

I want to compose the docker file with postgres and redis images.
I'm beginner to Docker and doing this first time.

Answer (score 2):

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4.21
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: myusername
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPass
  ports:
    -'5432:5432'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

redis:
  image: redis: 5.0.5
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data

mobydock:
  build: .
  command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --access-logfile - "mobydock.app:create_app()"
  environment:
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/mobydock
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
```

yaml is indent sensitive

Comment: Mind the `-` in the volumes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is YAML syntax not being respected - if you are new to YAML you can find plenty of resources on the web - such as:

- you must use two spaces for indentation of each mapping
- when listing elements (such as volumes or ports) you must use `-` for each element in the list
- when using strings with YAML characters (such as `:`) it's better to quote them (i.e. `image: "redis:5.0.5"` instead of `image: redis: 5.0.5`

You also have a few docker-compose syntax related issues:

- Volumes is a not a proper list and you'd better use absolute path instead of relative ones (do not use `~/path` in Compose), for example:

  ```
  volumes:
    - /home/user/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
  ```
- In your file, `image` will be read as an element of `volumes`, i.e. your indentation is not correct. Instead of using:

  ```
  # YAML will interpret image as being under the volume key
  volumes:
    - /home/user/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
    image: [...]
  ```

  You should have:

  ```
  # mind the space indentation !
  volumes:
    - /home/user/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
  image: [...]
  ```

  This indentation error is also present on most of the other elements, check the [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) syntax to know the ordering of each elements.

You can use a YAML Linter such [as this one](http://www.yamllint.com/) to help solve these YAML syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

`volumes` is a list, so you should write :

```
volumes:
  - ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
```

Moreover your file is incorrectly indented, it should be written this way :

```yaml
postgres:
  image: "postgres:9.4.21"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: myusername
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPass
  ports:
    -'5432:5432'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

redis:
  image: "redis:5.0.5"
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/mobydock/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data

mobydock:
  build: .
  command: 'gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --access-logfile - "mobydock.app:create_app()"'
  environment:
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/mobydock
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
```